# 401 error after redirecting to Tomcat web application when using CAS

Tags: tomcat, cas

I am trying to configure Tomcat and CAS.

My deployment has:
1. Single Tomcat server (version 7.0.29)
2. Apache DS as the LDAP
3. CAS server 3.5.2 deployed to Tomcat
4. My web application is deployed to the same Tomcat server

I'm using self-signed certs and had to modify CAS to provide a custom HostNameVerifier to get past wrong hostname errors.

So now when I try to access my web application I get redirected to the CAS login page. I can login using credentials from the LDAP and get redirected back to the web application. But I get a 401 when using CAS20 authenticator (got 403 when I tried SAML11 authenticator).

So I suspect something may be wrong with the web.xml. Here is what I'm using:

```
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>Global Access</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Global</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>*</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Any ideas on what I have done wrong?

thanks
Mark

CAS Trace

```
2013-09-07 11:45:33,206 INFO  [com.github.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager] - <Audit trail record BEGIN
=============================================================
WHO: [username: fadams]
WHAT: supplied credentials: [username: fadams]
ACTION: AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Sat Sep 07 11:45:33 BST 2013
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 127.0.0.1
SERVER IP ADDRESS: 127.0.0.1
=============================================================

>
2013-09-07 11:45:33,209 INFO [com.github.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager] - <Audit trail record BEGIN
=============================================================
WHO: [username: fadams]
WHAT: TGT-1-1cSjhWvG2A6kQcEJVOFkHAiQgGRyejeoVkpTkzbqSBftS7LApp-localhost
ACTION: TICKET_GRANTING_TICKET_CREATED
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Sat Sep 07 11:45:33 BST 2013
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 127.0.0.1
SERVER IP ADDRESS: 127.0.0.1
=============================================================

>
2013-09-07 11:45:33,212 INFO [org.jasig.cas.CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl] - <Granted service ticket [ST-1-vjLbc7KbWAK5kyYTSJTZ-localhost] for service [https://localhost:8443/moodle.webapp/] for user [fadams]>
2013-09-07 11:45:33,212 INFO [com.github.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager] - <Audit trail record BEGIN
=============================================================
WHO: fadams
WHAT: ST-1-vjLbc7KbWAK5kyYTSJTZ-localhost for https://localhost:8443/moodle.webapp/
ACTION: SERVICE_TICKET_CREATED
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Sat Sep 07 11:45:33 BST 2013
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 127.0.0.1
SERVER IP ADDRESS: 127.0.0.1
=============================================================

>
Warning: URL Host: localhost vs. localhost
2013-09-07 11:45:33,259 INFO [com.github.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager] - <Audit trail record BEGIN
=============================================================
WHO: audit:unknown
WHAT: ST-1-vjLbc7KbWAK5kyYTSJTZ-localhost
ACTION: SERVICE_TICKET_VALIDATED
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Sat Sep 07 11:45:33 BST 2013
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 127.0.0.1
SERVER IP ADDRESS: 127.0.0.1
=============================================================
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have all the necessary CAS filters in place in the webapp, most notably the ticket validation filter and the request wrapper filter? Look e.g. here for details: https://wiki.jasig.org/plugins/servlet/mobile#content/view/8096602